# How to analyse this plot?

Tags: regression, time-series

How to interpret this fitted vs data(actual) plot? My data is time series and there are many observations for the y variable for one year.

How to analyse it if my data is a time series? This is a multiple linear regression model. I am  confused on how to analyse it.

[image: fiited against actual data plot]

---

So, this is my time series linear model. My objective is to find the variable that has the most influence on the life expectancy. So, I was told to do this fitted vs actual data plot. But, I do not know how to analyze it.

[image: Time series linear model]

This is the correlation heat map.
[image: heat map]

[image: line graph of life expectancy]
[image: bar graph_gender]
[image: bar graph_age]
[image: bar graph_race]

This is how my data looks like, that's y I have 756 observations.
[image: data frame]

My original data
[image: original data]

Then, I categorised the age variable.[image: categorising age]
[image: count of age group]

Then, I made age >60 to be the baseline (1).
[image: rearrange]

And another thing is, the entries for female and male is the same. Same goes for race variable.

[image: gender]
[image: race]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited out the tag `acf-pacf` which on the face of it is not just irrelevant, but also a major distraction. Feel free to re-insert it if that is wrong. For more on that detail, please see my answer. However, I have not edited your title, because part of an answer should be to flag misconceptions if they appear to be part of a question.

Comment: For Malaysia, I have a hard time accepting `Race` as either measured or binary. What is the coding there?  Also, if your data are pooling different years, how is it also a time series? People not using R need some explanation of what `tslm()` does and doesn't do.

Comment: @Nick I did edit the title because it's just too misleading.

Comment: I agree that the coding of race is not arbitrary here and more detail could be offered. It may aid answerers if you provide scatterplots of your data, as suggested by Nick in his answer.

Comment: I have added the graphs

Comment: It seems that you have  3 distinct values of age, 3 distinct values of race, 2 genders and 7 years. That would be 3 x 3 x 2 x 7 = 126 observations, so where do the extra df come from? Moreover, if I understand this correctly age and race should be treated as factor variables -- and year belongs in the model. Where does the outlier on your first plot come from?

Comment: So, the data are for individuals.  But "life expectancy" is in my experience always an expectation for people with given characteristics, how much longer they are expected to live. If life expectancy is (as I now guess) age at death. what does age group mean?

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail, but I am still pretty lost on what you're trying to do and even on what the outcome variable is precisely.  It seems that you have fine age groups and are then coarsening them. I can't see any value in doing that. Sorry, but I doubt I can help further.

Comment: I am trying to do forecasting to find the variable that has the most influence on the life expectancy. So, I am checking assumptions for time series linear model (tslm). That's y I made the fitted vs data plot.

Answer (score 1):

If time series are mentioned, ACF plot for me implies a graph of the autocorrelation function, not the case here.

Your plot is instead fitted versus actual given a model fit. This is quite a common plot across many fields, although practice varies on which variable goes on which axis and what to call each variable or the plot as a whole. I've seen mention of {observed} on the one hand and {predicted, forecast} on the other hand and names such as calibration plots, distortion plots and fitted value plots.

That's all secondary.

**How to interpret your graph depends intimately on the exact model you are fitting, what is the outcome or response and what predictors did you use.**

I guess wildly that your data include

life expectancies for quite different age groups

and for different years

and that in essence age group is in that comparison utterly dominant -- no surprise as the life expectancy of a 1 year old is utterly different from that of a 80 year old. This interpretation follows from noticing a dominant pattern of more or less horizontal bands.

What do you expect to learn from your model fit? You might expect to see some effects of the covid pandemic. If you have predictors such as ethnicity as well, then it could be interesting to see if different races differ given age group and year.

You have one outlier at data around 20 and fitted about 60. That's a cause for major concern. An anomaly so strong with this kind of data suggests to me a data entry error -- or alternatively very high mortality given the pandemic among very elderly people.

I am very positive about plotting both raw data and the results of a model fit, but here a table of parameter estimates together with confidence intervals and so forth is likely to be much more informative. But the graph is worthwhile alone for exposing a serious outlier.