# How to check assumptions for time series linear regression?

Tags: regression, time-series, diagnostic

So, I am checking the assumptions for my time series data.

[image: ACF plot]

I also did this test and it seems to reject the null hypotheses.

[image: Breusch test]

Then, to check the equal variances, I made a box plot.
[image: gender]
[image: age]
[image: race]
So, I found that for age variable, all the groups have non-similar variances. So, how am I supposed to conclude the equal variances of the entire data?

For outliers, I made a box plot too.

[image: outlier]

I found that only variable age has an outlier. So, how to fix this?

And, what plot should I use to check the linearity for this time series data?

Comment: Why do you want to check the assumptions? What do you want to use your model for? The assumptions of linear regression are obviously not met because it assumes independent errors, while time-series means that the subsequent observations are correlated.

Comment: This is a variant on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618079/how-to-analyse-this-plot and unfortunately subject to the same problem in my view: it is impossible to comment helpfully without a direct explanation of the OP's data and goals and the model fitted!

Comment: The outlier has already been mentioned in the thread just cited as one where the observed value is about 20 and one model predicts 60. From above, it occurs for Age == 3, Race == 1, Gender == 1. It should be easy enough to find in the data,

Comment: The outlier also is shown at about index 410 in the very first graph.